# Инициализировать слайдер swiper во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Как при получении результата в методе `getUser()` переинициализировать swiper?

```
<template>
    <div class="dating">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="dating_cards">
                <ul class="dating_cards--wrapp">
                    <li v-if="users.length > 0" v-for="(user,index) in users" :data-partner-id="user.id">
                        <div class="data--user__header">
                            <p class="username">{{user.fullname}}, {{user.age}} </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dating--user_img dating__img">
                            <div class="swiper-container">
                                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                    <div class="swiper-slide dating__slide is-verified"   data-verif-text="Фото проверено">
                                        <img alt="avatar" :src="'/storage/'+user.avatar">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="swiper-slide dating__slide is-verified"  v-for="image in user.images"  data-verif-text="Фото проверено">
                                        <img alt="avatar" :src="'/storage/'+image.path+image.image">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dating__navigation" v-if="not_user === 0">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="dating__keyboards--box">
                    <div class="dating__keyboards-item">
                        <div class="icon--key">
                            <svg><use xlink:href="#left__arrow"></use></svg>
                        </div>
                        <span>Не нравиться</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dating__keyboards-item">
                        <div class="icon--key">
                            Пробел
                        </div>
                        <span>Следующее фото</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dating__keyboards-item">
                        <div class="icon--key">
                            <svg><use xlink:href="#right__arrow"></use></svg>
                        </div>
                        <span>Нравиться</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        name: "Dating",
        data: function() {
            return {
                min: 18,
                max: 35,
                users: [],
                attribute: [],
                images: [],


            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.getUser();
        },
        methods: {
            getUser(){
                axios.post('/dating/search',{min:this.min, max: this.max})
                    .then((response) => {
                            this.users = response.data

                    })
                    .catch(error => {});
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: под этот плагин есть vue-обертка. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-awesome-swiper

Comment: а как сделать инициализацию слайдов?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так, или создавать экземпляр Swiper в методах, и через вызов метода инициализировать его.

```js
import Swiper from 'swiper/js/swiper.esm.bundle';

const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // ...
});

export default {
  name: "Dating",
  data: function() {
    return {
      min: 18,
      max: 35,
      users: [],
      attribute: [],
      images: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUser();
  },
  methods: {
    getUser() {
      axios.post('/dating/search', {
          min: this.min,
          max: this.max
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.users = response.data
          swiper.init(); // <----
        })
        .catch(error => {});
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: Так не работает все ровно